# Bash Script - Divide Colum 2 by Colum in the middle but keep 1 and 4 on either side

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list that has an ID, population, area and province, that looks like this:

```
1:517000:405212:Newfoundland and Labrador
2:137900:5660:Prince Edward Island
3:751400:72908:New Brunswick
4:938134:55284:Nova Scotia
5:7560592:1542056:Quebec
6:12439755:1076359:Ontario
7:1170300:647797:Manitoba
8:996194:651036:Saskatchewan
9:3183312:661848:Alberta
10:4168123:944735:British Comumbia
11:42800:1346106:Northwest Territories
12:31200:482443:Yukon Territories
13:29300:2093190:Nunavut
```

I need display the names of the provinces with the lowest and highest population density (population/area). How can I divide column 1 by column 2 (2 decimal places) but keep the file information in tact on either side (eg. 1:**1.28**:Newfoundland and Labrador). After that I figure I can just pump it into `sort -t: -nk2 | head -n 1` and `sort -t: -nrk2 | head -n 1` to pull them.

The recommended command given was grep.

Comment: You might want to look into `awk`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was going to use awk for the final output (_awk -F: '{print $4" has the lowest population density."}'_). Are you saying I'm able to use it for the math too?

Comment: Yes, `awk` can do the math too.  It can do the math, the line selection, and everything else you want to do all in one.

Comment: Thanks to your reply I am really close. The only problem I have now is awk removes my dividing colon. Probably something really simple to put it back. I have:

`join -t: -13 -22 ./files/capitals.sorted ./files/provinces.sorted | awk -F: '{$5=$2/$3;print}' | sort -t: -nrk1 | head -n 1 | awk -F" " '{print $4" has the highest population density."}'`. In the second awk command I have a space as the separator testing it.

Comment: I wrote an answer with an example awk script.  Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: I used `join -t: -13 -22 ./files/capitals.sorted ./files/provinces.sorted | awk -F: '{print $1,$2/$3,$4}' OFS=: OFMT="%.2f"` based on your solution and it worked great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to have the sorting and extraction under control, here's an example awk script that should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=":"
    OFS=":"
    OFMT="%.2f"
}

{
    print $1,$2/$3,$4
}
```

Comment: Your OFS is what I was missing in my implementation. Thanks! Now I can work on making it simpler. I have `join -t: -13 -22 ./files/capitals.sorted ./files/provinces.sorted | awk -F: '{$5=$2/$3;print}' OFS=: | sort -t: -nrk5 | head -n 1 | awk -F: '{print $4" has the highest population density."}'` and it works in a sloppy way.